# Send email verification code to another base_url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, email-verification

I have two laravel systems and both connected to one master database

```
1.customer portal-customer.test
2.admin portal - admin.test
```

Customers are not allowed to access to the admin portal

But admin can create customers from admin dashboard.

Customers cannot' login to their profile until they verify their email.

Currently if an user creates an account directly through the customer portal, the user receive the verification email and if he/she clicks on the link with in 60 minutes, account get verified and activated.

verification link look like this:

```
http://customer.test/email/verify/13/976bdd188ad675ad87c827ca9723fb4a7bda2178?expires=1588242534&signature=cc628ef025eb7cd03fe76093be1e9e3fdfce12f5208c185560d1996b9f662744
```

But now when the admin creates an user account for a customer through the admin panel(admin.test)same process need to be happened.

Following is my user create function in the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required','email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:12', 'confirmed','regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{12,}$/'],
            'mobile'=>['required', 'regex:/^\+[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{8})$/','numeric','min:9'],
            'username'=>['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:10', 'unique:users'],   
            'roles'=>['required'],
            'user_roles'=>['required'],
        ]);

        //Customer::create($request->all());

        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);

        $user = User::create($input);
        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

        event(new Registered($user));
        //$user->notify(new SendRegisterMailNotification());

        return redirect()->route('customers.index')
                        ->with('success','Customer created successfully. Verification email has been sent to user email.  ');
    }
```

Here also user create successfully, email also send to the user's email BUT the issue is verification link's base url.... it has to be, customer.test but it inclludes admin.test.....So now when ever a user clicks on that link it'll take customer to a link like,

```
http://admin.test/email/verify/22/3b7c357f630a62cb2bac0e18a47610c245962182?expires=1588247915&signature=7e6869deb1b6b700dcd2a49b2ec66ae32fb0b6dc99aa0405095e9844962bb53c
```

As the customers are not allowed to admin panel user gets a 403 forbidden message..

So how can I change this Base url???

```
event(new Registered($user));
```

handles the email sending once when the user is being created..

Comment: Please show what is in your `Registered` event handler/listener. You'll need to add the URL in the listener to send the email. If I see the listener I can provide a solution.

Comment: @ChristopheHubert where can I find that?

Comment: @Etin, he is using the default `Registered` event - may need to create a custom event for that

Answer (score 0):

In your `SendRegisterMailNotification` you need to correctly add the base URL you want. It could be any thing you want or you could add it to your app config and env as `app.customer_base_url` and then reference this in your Notification.

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SendRegisterMailNotification extends Notification
{
    ...
    public function toMail($notifiable) {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('Click here to verify')
            ->action('Verify', 'http://customer.test/' . $this->url);
            //$this->url gotten however you usually get the verification url.
    }
}
```

Comment: well, that line has been commented in my code, look closely

Comment: Please show what's in the event handler, I asked for this prior. Although, the logic is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your `EventServiceProvider` you need to create your custom listener for `Registered`

```
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            CustomSendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Where you will handle your logic to set the base url

Comment: I am sorry but i'm not getting that properly, can you expand the answer please? i already have this in my EventServicerovider, protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
    ];